# Can a magnet stop when falling through a copper tube?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, lenz-law

It is known that when a magnet falls through a copper tube, it slows down according to the Lenz's Law. So theoretically if the magnet falls fast enough, can it completely stop for a moment?
I have done some calculations and turns out 0.5cmX1cm magnet has to fall at the speed around $5*10^6 km/h$. It seems unreal, so is it even possible?[image: first page][image: second page]

Comment: Please, spend some time typing the equations in MathJax. As it is right now it is not easy to read. Spending some time to format a question nicely shows that you do care for it and you respect the time other people will spend to try and help you.

Comment: Well if the magnet falls fast it can't be at rest. And if the magnet is at rest, there is no induced electric field of magnet acting on the tube and stirring up current, so the magnet will experience only weak force due to remaining currents in the tube. Only when it moves, is there a force opposing gravity. Thus unless the magnet is supported by some other force, the gravity will have its way and the magnet will fall down with non-zero speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So theoretically if the magnet falls fast enough, can it completely stop for a moment?*
No.
The falling magnet induces an emf in the copper because there is relative movement between the magnet and the copper. [Faraday]
The induced emf in the copper produces an induced current in the copper which in turn produces a magnetic field which opposes the motion of the magnet. [Lenz]
If the magnet were to stop there would be no induced emf, no induced current and no opposition to the motion of the magnet.
Thus the magnet can never stop but rather it could reach a terminal velocity at which time the net force on the magnet is zero with the induced magnetic field force equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the gravitational attraction.

Answer (score 4):

You have just calculated where the induced fields balance the field of the magnet (approximately). I suspect what you really wanted to do was calculate the speed at which the force between the magnet and the induced field, which increases with speed, balances the weight of the magnet.

This would just mean the acceleration was zero, not the velocity.

The situation is similar to an object falling through a fluid. The frictional forces grow with speed until they approach balancing the weight of the object. Then the acceleration is zero and the object approaches a terminal velocity.

The same will happen for the magnet in a conducting tube, or indeed a magnet sliding down a conductive surface. It doesn't come to rest, it reaches a terminal velocity.